# Show a field of a modelformset as a value

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got the following generating and displaying a formset:

```
SessionPlannerTraineeFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    PerformedLesson, fields=['trainee', 'lesson', 'instructor'],
)
performed_lessons_formset=SessionPlannerTraineeFormSet(
    queryset=PerformedLesson.objects.filter(session=self.object),
)


<table class="table">
    <tr><th>Trainee</th><th>Lesson</th><th>Instructor</th></tr>
    {% for form in performed_lessons_formset %}
        <tr><td>{{form.trainee}}</td><td>{{form.lesson}}</td><td>{{form.instructor}}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I'd like the trainee just to show its value. I've tried `{{form.trainee.value}}`, however because trainee is a ForeignKey to a user all I get is the pk of that user as that's whats being fed to the HTML `<select>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bumped into the answer while working on another form:

```
{{form.instance.trainee}}
```

Could then chop `trainee` out of the `fields=[]` definition as well